# Daily Index Blocking

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, index-maintenance

There is ONE index rebuild which everyday is blocked causing the job to fail.  It is the same index and same stored procedure which blocks.  We used an automated stored procedure to rebuild or reorg each index based on fragmentation.  How can I fix this issue?  Any ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is the error, show us the relevant portion of the automated stored procedure

Comment: Could you post the code of the sp that is blocking your reindex? Also, have you tried [`REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON)`?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/guidelines-for-online-index-operations?view=sql-server-2017) or, in that case, just swap to [Ola's scripts](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) and tweak the options as needed?

Comment: The stored procedure where the blocking is occurring is conducting multiple inserts/updates and deletes.  How to handle?  Should I change the job time?

Comment: You could stop rebuilding the index, and try just updating statistics instead.

Answer (score 1):

We face this daily at work too, DBCC or Re-Index run into lock timeouts/blocks

What we can do (there's no one solution)

- Check the blocking query (we have job to save lock/deadlock every
  minute), investigate root cause, and fix if possible
- Change timing of Re-Index job if possible
- For SQL Job, set Retry
- Check Ola's dbo.CommandLog table (used by
  IndexOptimize) to see the error -> from there we can copy command
  manually to re-run, or use procedure to re-run the "failed commands"
  only